# Lock wait timeout exceeded on INSERT

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-aurora

I have a table `Contact` on MySQL 5.7 (running on AWS RDS Aurora) that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Contact (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    createdAt DATETIME,
    updatedAt DATETIME
);
```

The table has 4 other tables connected to it via `Contact.id` but the relation is not enforced with a foreign key.
The production table contains over 10M rows. I recently wrote a NodeJS script that grabs a list of contact ids and runs DELETE queries on the `Contact` table. The important part looks like this:

```
await this.query("DELETE FROM AssociatedTableA WHERE contactId=?", contactId);
await this.query("DELETE FROM AssociatedTableB WHERE contactId=?", contactId);
await this.query("DELETE FROM AssociatedTableC WHERE contactId=?", contactId);
await this.query("DELETE FROM AssociatedTableD WHERE contactId=?", contactId);
await this.query("DELETE FROM Contact WHERE contactId=?", contactId);
```

The above part runs for every contact id that is parsed from a series CSV files containing 2.5M rows. Multiple worker processes parse the CSV files and execute the snippet.
It's not part of a transaction and there are no explicit locks

While this script is running the application is live on production and users are registering Contacts. After a few deletes though, INSERTS were blocked with the following error:

```
ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT: Lock wait timeout exceeded - try restarting transaction
```

No new contact could be added, even after stopping all worker processes and restarting the database. I had to put the app on maintenance mode and kill any remaining connections to MySQL.

So my question is, what type of lock could possibly block an Insert query? Isn't MySQL InnoDB supposed to never lock the entire table?

Comment: do youy need to commit the transactions?

Comment: @akaphenom I do not have a transaction. That's the weird part

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Aurora is not MySQL. It has a lot of code in common, but they rewrote a lot particularly in the storage engine, which is where row-level locking is implemented. Aurora is not open-source, and we can't run it other than in the managed Amazon environment, so it's hard to test or debug. So who knows what locking behavior of InnoDB they have changed?

For InnoDB, INSERTs can be blocked by gap locks, next-key locks, auto-increment locks, or metadata locks. In my experience, the former two of those are most likely to give the ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT error if there's an outstanding lock blocking them.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks